# How to set environment variables for build

Tags: sunstudio

I'm using Sun Studio 12, but I'll take help for any version that you are familiar with.

I have a proejct based on existing code and Makefiles. The build toolchain I'm using has various options that are read from environment variables. I see that I can set up environment variables for runtime within the project settings, but I can't see any options for setting environment variables for building the project.

Is this possible to do in Sun Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variables in your shell (make sure they are exported) then build
your project with

```
$ make -e
```

That's not specific to any version of Studio, or the GNU toolchain, that's a feature of the make utility which has been there for ....... a very long time.